# How to trigger div visibility when hovering over list item in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to hide a div using the css property `visibility: none` when a user hovers over a link wrapped in a list item.

HTML

```
<div id="rightnav" class="navbar-header pull-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a id="home" href="." data-pjax="content">Works</a></li>
      <li><a id="about" href="studio.php" data-pjax="content">Studio</a></li>
      <li><a id="contact" href="formspree.php" data-pjax="content">Contact</a></li>
      <div id="bar1"></div>
      <div id="bar2"></div>
      <div id="bar3"></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Is there a way to select the divs with id 'bar_*' when a user hovers over one of the list items (#home, #about, #contact) purely using CSS? I'm not opposed to using jQuery/Javascript, just trying to figure out the simplest way forward & found this surprisingly tricky.

Comment: If that #bar is a child of LI is much more easier with the use of CSS but you can do this in jquery..

Comment: @NelsonTan jQuery unnecessary, document.querySelector API can do all the same selectors as sizzle engine and is built into all current browsers.

Comment: Haha, I'd much rather stick to CSS if possible! So, just to clarify: if I want to hide 'bar1' when hovering over #home using nothing but CSS, I should wrap the div within the li tag?

Comment: Definitely possible with pure CSS, you could probably restructure to make it less complex however.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for clarifying & will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple with css try this **fiddle link** :https://jsfiddle.net/xfz6x9wt/

```
ul{
height:30px;
}
ul li a {

color:green}

ul li a:hover {
color:red;
}

 ul li a:hover + div.hide{
color:red;
visibility:hidden;
}

<ul><li><a href="#">hii</a>
<div class="hide"> hide</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the method I ended up using! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id=^bar]')).forEach(x => x.style.visibility = 'hidden')
```

to select all elements with id starting with bar.

[MDN Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I ended up going the pure CSS route after fiddling with how my html was laid out

Answer (score 0):

You can use sibling selector coupled with hover. Hope this is what you are looking for:

```css
#rightnav div{
  background: red;
  display: block;
}

#rightnav #bar1{
  background: red;
}

#rightnav #bar2{
  background: blue;
}

#rightnav #bar3{
  background: green;
}

li:nth-child(1):hover ~ div:nth-of-type(1){
  display: none !important;
}
li:nth-child(2):hover ~ div:nth-of-type(2){
  display: none !important;
}
li:nth-child(3):hover ~ div:nth-of-type(3){
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="rightnav" class="navbar-header pull-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a id="home" href="." data-pjax="content">Works</a></li>
      <li><a id="about" href="studio.php" data-pjax="content">Studio</a></li>
      <li><a id="contact" href="formspree.php" data-pjax="content">Contact</a></li>
      <div id="bar1">Home</div>
      <div id="bar2">About</div>
      <div id="bar3">Contact</div>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! While I didn't use this method exactly, your answer helped me better understand my options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For simplicity, you can restructure your html like this:

```
<div id="rightnav" class="navbar-header pull-right">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
      <a id="home" href="." data-pjax="content">Works</a>
      <div class="nav-content">Item-1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="about" href="studio.php" data-pjax="content">Studio</a>
      <div class="nav-content">Item-2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="contact" href="formspree.php" data-pjax="content">Contact</a>
      <div class="nav-content">Item-3</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-nav li:hover .nav-content {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

> Ref: http://jsbin.com/xekojel/edit?html,css,output